# Form load Event fires twice, using Interop Forms Toolkit

Tags: vb.net, forms, interop, toolkit

I've been following a codeproject article on using the interop forms toolkit (basically a way for developers to slowly upgrade their VB6 projects to .net by allowing .net components run in VB6)

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb-interop/VB6InteropToolkit2.aspx

While the .NET form is working fine in all other testing projects and environments, I've found that the Form_load event is actually firing twice once it's in executing in the VB6 runtime.

Not only annoying, its forcing my initialization code to execute twice (causing all kind of problems on the second run).

Is there any explanation as to why this is happening (I'd like to understand the reason)?

Is there anything better way to work-around this apart from

```
 If (runBefore = True) Then
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible for this occur if you implicitly begin loading a form by accessing a public variable in the form from another module, then explicitly .show the form before the loading is complete.

Comment: Possibly.  The interop wrappers (generated by the toolkits template) could be making the calls.

Comment: That is what was happening to me, had to set some properties before loading the form... makes sense as to why it does it based on how VB6 forms worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

hi i've tried this and it works..

i put it in form_activate. basically to test if the form is already loaded. if it is, then unload it. I use i as counter.

Private Sub Form_Activate()

```
Dim TestForm As Form
i = 0
For Each TestForm In Forms
    If TestForm.Name = "frmStocks" Then i = i + 1
    If i = 2 Then Unload Me
Next TestForm
```

End Sub